# Jointplot multiindex columns with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'col2': ['A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'A1']})

              col1  col2

0   A   A1
1   A   B1
2   B   B1
3   B   B1
4   B   A1
```

I did a groupby. The result was a multiindex column

```
df = df.groupby(['col1']).agg({'col2': ['nunique','count']})

       col2
       nunique   count
 col1       
 A     2           2
 B     2           3
```

Then, I did a jointplot from seaborn library

```
sns.jointplot(x=['col2','nunique'],y=['col2','count'],data=df,kind='scatter')
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

My question is :

Is there a way to split the multiindex column into two seperate columns like this?

```
col1  col2_unique col2_count        
 A     2           2
 B     2           3
```

or

Is there a ways to jointplot a multiindex column?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change aggregate by specify column `col2` in list and in `agg` use only aggregate function for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].agg(['nunique','count'])
print(df)
      nunique  count
col1                
A           2      2
B           2      3

sns.jointplot(x='nunique', y='count', data=df, kind='scatter')
```

---

Or flatten `MultiIndex` if need use `dictinary` in `agg` - e.g. aggregate another column:

```
df = df.groupby(['col1']).agg({'col2': ['nunique','count'], 'col1':['min']})

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
     col1_min  col2_nunique  col2_count
col1                                   
A           A             2           2
B           B             2           3
```